# Unable to handle Push notifications on newer Android Devices

Tags: android, api, notifications, push-notification, deprecated

The following is the function responsible for handling a push notification received by my app. It is supposed to redirect the user to a certain Activity in the app after he/she clicks clicks on the notification.

When I try running the app on my Android 2.3.6(API 10) device,the notifications are handled perfectly.
However,when I try running it on an AVD( Andriod 4.3 (API 18)),there is no effect- the default android logo is displayed as icon instead of ic_launcher.png, the user is not redirected to the app on click,the notification does not autohide on clicking.

Please note,that I am using if statements to check API version of the phone on which the app is installed so as to ensure that push notifications are not affected by deprecated classes.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void createNotification(Context context, String payload) {


        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if (currentapiVersion >= 11)    {

           Intent intent = new Intent(context, tabswipe.MainActivity.class);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
           NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from ggg")
            .setContentText("zzzz")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pendingIntent)
            .build();
            notificationManager.notify(0, n); 
       }
       if (currentapiVersion < 11)  {
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, tabswipe.MainActivity.class);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
           NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"New Update from VIIT Perception", System.currentTimeMillis());
           notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; // Hide the notification after its selected
           notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; //adding LED lights to notification
           notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Updates from VIIT Perception", payload, pendingIntent);
           notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
       }
}
```

Comment: Please see this helpful page http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: What does this have to do with push notifications?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party service to send push notifications, I receive the push notifications but I'm unable to redirect the user to the app after he clicks on the notification.